# Windows CAPI CryptDecrypt error key not working

Tags: c++, c, windows, cryptography, cryptoapi

I am trying to decrypt data from openssl generated private key. I have converted the public key from PEM to DER format, but when i use CryptDecrypt it throws error `key does not exist`. I have previously used the same method to encrypt data and decrypt using openssl, i am also aware regarding the Endianess difference in openssl and wincrypto. Here is the code if someone can point out where i am going wrong.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")


char default_pub_key[] =
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"
"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVTOXB/Ti8SFvP42Z1XFB6GQ+R"
"jnqs42XiTFRXWpsSTlSPMRHi8aXpf1KYzzKHMC+4hU3rrgdbOu8bl7FekDoy38No"
"PX8ACoEmRhdn8mXs+ftmIRCuEE44mtgWUme65A1nTyT8nRmAVF6roo/rry+Xkbe9"
"iC6vRBRbVzprmCv7jwIDAQAB"
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
DWORD dwKeySize = 0;

void SwapBytes(char* pv, size_t n) {
    char* p = pv;
    size_t lo, hi;
    for (lo = 0, hi = n - 1; hi > lo; lo++, hi--)
    {
        char tmp = p[lo];
        p[lo] = p[hi];
        p[hi] = tmp;
    }
}

int init_crypto()
{
    LPBYTE pbBuffer;
    DWORD dwKeyBlob, dw_pub_key_len = 0;
    unsigned int offset = 22; // 22 = 1024, 24 = 2048 and so on
    DWORD dwParamSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO* publicKeyInfo;

    
    CryptStringToBinaryA(default_pub_key, 0, CRYPT_STRING_ANY, NULL, &dw_pub_key_len, NULL, NULL);

    pbBuffer = (LPBYTE)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dw_pub_key_len);
    CryptStringToBinaryA(default_pub_key, 0, CRYPT_STRING_ANY, pbBuffer, &dw_pub_key_len, NULL, NULL);

    dwKeyBlob = 0;
    CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, pbBuffer, dw_pub_key_len, 0, NULL, NULL, &dwKeyBlob);

    publicKeyInfo = (CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwKeyBlob);
    CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, pbBuffer, dw_pub_key_len, 0, NULL, publicKeyInfo, &dwKeyBlob);
    


    CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);


    CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(hProv, X509_ASN_ENCODING, publicKeyInfo, &hKey);


    CryptGetKeyParam(hKey, KP_KEYLEN, (BYTE*)&dwKeySize, &dwParamSize, 0);


    char da[16];
    memset(da, 0, sizeof(da));
    wsprintfA(da, "%d", dwKeySize);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, da, NULL, MB_OK);

    dwKeySize /= 8;

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    // start rsa crypto key
    init_crypto();


    // Read encrypted data
    DWORD junk;
    HANDLE hEncFile = CreateFile(L"test_enc.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD EncFileSize = GetFileSize(hEncFile, 0);
    char* EncFileBuf = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, EncFileSize + 1);
    ReadFile(hEncFile, EncFileBuf, EncFileSize, &junk, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hEncFile);


    // convert for win32
    SwapBytes((char*)EncFileBuf, EncFileSize);

    CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0,(PBYTE)EncFileBuf, &EncFileSize);

    
    hEncFile = CreateFile(L"test_dec.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    WriteFile(hEncFile, EncFileBuf, EncFileSize, &junk, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hEncFile);
    

    GlobalFree(EncFileBuf);



    // Do proper cleanup

    return 0;
    

}
```

Comment: because with public key you can only encrypt data. for decrypt you need full key - public+ private

Comment: Better use CNG.

Comment: yes, better. but result will be the same

Answer (score 0):

[CryptDecrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenkey)

> `[in] hKey`
>
> A handle to the key to use for the decryption. An application obtains this handle by using either the [CryptGenKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt) or [CryptImportKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptimportkey) function.

You pass a wrong hKey to CryptDecrypt. Use CryptImportKey after CryptImportPublicKeyInfo for getting an expected hKey and pass it to CryptDecrypt.

Comment: no, this is wrong. use `CryptImportPublicKeyInfo` is ok for get key

Comment: @RbMm What is wrong? CryptDecrypt requires a private key handle, CryptImportPublicKeyInfo returns a public key handle that is not valid for CryptDecrypt. A private key may be retrieved from a store using a public key handle passed to CryptImportKey.

Comment: yes, CryptDecrypt requires a private key handle. i also say this in comment under question. *CryptImportPublicKeyInfo returns a public key handle that is not valid for CryptDecrypt* - also true. but you not explain this from begin in answer.

Comment: i am trying to build an end2end encryption communication without sharing the private key to the other end of the party, is thre any reliable way to decrypt data using public key and without using openssl